# Entering cmd commands in a opened cmd for python script

Tags: python, windows, cmd, admin

I have a guest account in my computer . From the guest account , i will launch the a cmd with my python script's sub.process command and launch an alternate elevated cmd

```
(eg . subprocess.call(['runas', '/username:admin', 'cmd']).
```

A elevated cmd will then be launched and in that admin cmd ,I would like to key in some other commands (eg. net localgroup administrators newadmin /add)  to add a new admin with my script. Any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Have your Python script create a (temporary) batch script and call that script instead of `cmd.exe`:

```
tempfile = 'C:\\path\\to\\some.cmd'

f = open(tempfile, 'w')
f.write('@echo off\n')
f.write('net localgroup administrators newadmin /add\n')
...
f.close()

subprocess.call(['runas', '/username:admin', tempfile])

os.remove(tempfile)
```